# Cannot Get Look Controls to work

Tags: reactjs, aframe, webvr

I cannot get the look controls to work with [aframe-react](https://github.com/ngokevin/aframe-react). WASD controls work fine, and the assets appear fine.

```
import React from 'react';
import 'aframe';
import {Entity, Scene, Animation} from 'aframe-react';

class AugmentedForest extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Scene>
        <a-assets>
          <img id="forest-360" src="./images/forest_360.JPG"/>
        </a-assets>
        <Entity>
          <Entity camera="" look-controls="" wasd-controls=""/>
        </Entity>
        <a-sky src="#forest-360"/>
      </Scene>
    );
  }
}

export default AugmentedForest;
```

Comment: Maybe try passing empty object? `look-controls={{}}`

Comment: Version of React?

Comment: React.js v15.3.0. Passing an empty object doesn't work. Also, I don't get the open hand icon like I do in the boiler plate code.